# removing the "ion-activatable" class from an ion-item

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I am using ionic 6 with angular. I have been trying to remove the ion-activatable class from an ion-item. I have tried getting the ElementRef of the ion-item and using “ionItemElementRef.nativeElement.classList.remove(“ion-activatable”)”. It doesn’t work. Similarly,
“ionItemElementRef.nativeElement.classList.contains(“ion-activatable”)” returns FALSE.
Whats interesting is that the output to the console of the classList is:

DOMTokenList [value: ‘’]

0: “item-interactive”

1: “item-select”

2: “item-has-placeholder”

3: “ion-color”

4: “ion-color-gainsboro”

5: “item”

6: “md”

7: “item-lines-none”

8: “item-fill-none”

9: “ion-activatable”

10: “ion-focusable”

11: “hydrated”

length: 12

value: “item-interactive item-select item-has-placeholder ion-color ion-color-gainsboro item md item-lines-none item-fill-none ion-activatable ion-focusable hydrated”

so the class clearly exists yet classList methods do nothing to it.

Then I tried using [ngClass]="{‘ion-activatable’:false}" in the ion-item in the html template. That doesn’t work either.

Finally, I tried [class.ion-activatable]=“false” in the ion-item in the html template, which also doesn’t work.

My question is , in general, how do you remove or add a class to an ionic component at runtime?

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Depends on when you do `.remove(“ion-activatable”)`, if you try to run it in `ngAfterViewInit()` it might work but it really depends when `ionItemElementRef` is available from template. It needs to be rendered before it can be accessed.

Comment: I did indeed put that code inside ngAfterViewInit(), as well as the printout I included above, so it is initialized at that time. The printout is performed before the uses of remove() and contains(). It's almost as if ionic has made the classes property immutable somehow , which seems ridiculous and counterproductive.